# java io catching exception

Tags: java, exception, io, try-catch

I am getting this error:

```
bill value:$ 0.10
bill value: $0.05
bill value: $0.01
bill value: $100.00
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at ReadMoney.main(ReadMoney.java:12)
```

==================
My code:

```
//import java.util.Date;
public class ReadMoney
{
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("money.out");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Object read;
        try
        {
            while ((read = ois.readObject()) != null)
            {
                if (read instanceof Bill)
                {
                    System.out.println("bill value: " + read);
                }
                else if (read instanceof Quarter)
                {
                }// while
                else if (read instanceof Dime)
                {
                    System.out.println("bill value:" + read);
                }
                else if (read instanceof Nickel)
                {
                    System.out.println("bill value:" + read);
                }
                else if (read instanceof Penny)
                {
                    System.out.println("bill value:" + read);
                }
                else if (read instanceof Bill)
                {
                    System.out.println("bill value:" + read );
                }

            Money quarter = (Money) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Quarter: "+ quarter);
            System.out.println("Quarter: "+ quarter);
            Money dime = (Money) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Dime:" + dime);
            Money nickel = (Money)ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Nickel:" + nickel);
            Money penny = (Money) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Penny:" + penny);
            Money bill = (Money) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Bill: " + bill);
        }// try
        } catch (IllegalBillException ibe)
        {
            System.out.println("End of file reached");
        }
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    }// main
}// class
```

I'm pretty sure my try and catch block is correct but my program is not printing the 2 quarters value and also the text saying "end of file reached" for some odd reason. =/

Comment: What are the contents of your file? Seems like it doesn't contain what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

You're catching `IllegalBillException` (whatever that is), but you aren't catching `EOFException` (or it's superclass, `IOException`).

Comment: Oh I see Thanks! I was missing another catch statements! Thanks fellows!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `while` condition, which tests for EOF with the null check, doesn't "protect" the stuff after "`}// try`", and hence the `readObject` calls after that point will attempt to read beyond EOF and get the exception.

You need to restructure your logic somehow.

Catching `EOFException` will make the exception "go away" but will not fix your bug.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks! It's fixed now! :)